# Checking if a string exists in an uninitialized array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization, exists

I have a helper function that determines if a string exists within an array of strings:

```
bool exists_in(char *string, char *array[], int size){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if(strcmp(string, array[i]) == 0)
            printf("%s\n", array[i]);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically, I want to put an element inside the array if it isn't already in there. How can I do this with an array that isn't initialized to have values in it?

```
char *myArray[100] // initailize array
```

I want to call exists_in() on myArray, but this will give me a segfault 11 because there are no values in the myArray.

Comment: Note that your `if` statement's braces are missing.

Comment: Doh. That saved me a lot of trouble, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `size` to indicate the number of *valid* entries if you fill the array up from 0 to `size-1`.

If the array is not filled consecutively, or if you may want to delete items from it afterwards, initialize the very first 'empty' array with `NULL` in each element. (Do not forget to reset an element back to `NULL` if you delete it later.)

Then add an explicit test on `NULL` in your loop before the `strcmp`:

```
char *myArray[100] = { NULL }; // initialize array with NULL
// (all elements will be initialized to 0 with this construction)

...

bool exists_in(char *string, char *array[], size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] && strcmp(string, array[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", array[i]);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the accepted answer by adding more utility functions

```
bool store_in(char *string, char *array[], size_t size);
bool delete_in(char *string, char *array[], size_t size);
```

and test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h> // bool C99

bool exists_in(char *string, char *array[], size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] && strcmp(string, array[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Exists:  %s\n", array[i]);
            return true; // exists
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool store_in(char *string, char *array[], size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            array[i] = string;

            printf("Storing: %s\n", array[i]);
            return true; // stored
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool delete_in(char *string, char *array[], size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] && strcmp(string, array[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Delete:  %s\n", array[i]);
            array[i] = NULL;
            return true; // deleted
        }
    }
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    char *my_array[100] = { NULL }; // initialize array with NULL
    // (all elements will be initialized to 0 with this construction)    

   //1.
   if (! exists_in("123", my_array, 100) ) // Does not exists 
       store_in("123",my_array, 100);      // It will store 
   printf("\n");

   //2.      
   if (! exists_in("123", my_array, 100))  // Exists
       store_in("123",my_array, 100);      // It will not store 
   printf("\n");    

    //3.
   if (exists_in("123", my_array, 100))  
       delete_in("123",my_array, 100);     // It will delete
    printf("\n");   

    //4.   
    if (! exists_in("123", my_array, 100)) // Does not exists 
       store_in("123",my_array, 100);     // It will store

    return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
Storing: 123

Exists:  123

Exists:  123
Delete:  123

Storing: 123
```